# Was one number short of getting the first prize!

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Context:
The number on my lottery ticket: 26381 
The official result for the first prize: 26384

(In my country, it's 2/6/3/8/1 - five different numbers. The numbers can repeat and are already printed on the tickets).

And I want to say "You missed one number, otherwise you would have won the first prize".So is "Was one number short of getting the first prize!" a correct sentence to express what I mean?

If not, how can I say that (I prefer an exclamatory sentence, if possible!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without explaining it, *one number short* may be misunderstood such as 4 or 5; 6 or 7, and so on. In short, number in *series.* But, out of many, in such cases, I use an idiom (since you asked for exclamatory!) [*hair's breadth.*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hairs-breadth)

> Ah....missed the lottery jackpot by *a hair's breadth.*

Or *just missed* is simple and easily understood.

> Ah...*just missed* the jackpot

Now, that's an idiomatic expression. If you want to emphasize on the *digit,* you may say,

> Missed the first prize by one digit

**But here,** you then need to explain what that *digit is.*

> The last digit is '4' and I have '1.'

As I said, it's just *one way* to tell this with exclamation. Wait for others to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I think any native speaker would understand **one number short** in the context of a lottery to mean that you had all but one of the numbers (not all but one of the digits that make up a number).

Suppose these were the winning numbers:

2, 16, 33, 41, 59

If you had 58 instead of 59, or 44 instead of 59, you could still say *I was one number short of winning the lottery*.

Comment: So you mean "was one number short of winning the 1st prize" is correct?

Comment: @haile: Yes, it is idiomatic, as per my examples.